# How to show Rate us Dialog by Detecting time spend in Separate Screens in Xcode7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode7, nstimer

I have developed and deployed my app in AppStore. It is running successfully.

Now I have a Logical issue while implementing a Rate us Dialog.

> I want to show a Custom dialog box when user has spend `5 mins` in my App and `30 Seconds` in any Screen.

Curently the only solution which comes in my mind is use of:

```
performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:
```

But I am not sure it is good or not.  Is their any other way to achieve this.

**Edit**:

I have Implemented this piece of code in ApplicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
    self.timerForScreenTimeOut =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(idleTimerExceeded) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Now How can I detect How many seconds elapsed in Particular screen before `poping` it out from `Navigation Controller`.

Comment: [take a look at this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/irate) & [others](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=rate)

Comment: 5 mins & 30 seconds for rate? Don't make rush to rate your app else you will have WRONG rating...

Comment: @FahimParkar I will do it only once or twice in a day... I am unable to track the screen switching...Thanks for your links...But I don't want to use any libraries for that..I have implemented al things..Only one problem I am facing :(

Comment: in such case I would keep keep the current time and start time in NSUserDefault and do all action as per difference between these two nsuserdefaults...

Answer (score 0):

```
you can call your method inside applicationWillEnterForeground:.
For example: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSTimer *rateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 5.0
                                                                   target: self
                                                                 selector: @selector(showRatePrompt)
                                                                 userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
            });
```

Comment: yes I have done this...But now How can I detect the time Elapsed in Screen

Comment: @RahulMishra Take a global int variable named seconds. create a timer on view didload and fire it. In the method of you timer, increase your seconds. thus u can get the time elapsed in screen.

Comment: I add it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

To detect the time elapsed in Screen

In **viewdidlod**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

    //create Global variable of NSInteger *seconds and initialise it with 0
    seconds = 0;

    NSTimer *Secondtimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(increaseTimeCount) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [Secondtimer fire];
}
```

And in your **increaseTimeCount** method, increase the seconds.

```
- (void)increaseTimeCount {
    seconds++;
}
```

So when **seconds** value will reach to 30, then you can show your alert and invalidate the timer.

Comment: I have more then 30 screens..And I have to manage all these screens

Comment: Then put this code in a common class or Appdelegate class, Every time when you enter in a new screen, you will start a timer which will increase your no of seconds and and the timer when user pop or dismiss. when ever user stay @ any screen more then 30 sec. you will be able to show your alert to rate the app